# How to access to my folders on android nexus 4 without OS

Tags: nexus-4, unbricking

I have a problem :
I tried to install the last update of Android 4.4 on my nexus 4
But It didn't work...
My phone didn't want to turn on. So I tried to uninstall everything an install the update manually.
But now I can't access to my phone on my computer...
he "sees" it but I can't go into it...
I tried to install differents drivers like : adb, google USB driver, MTP. But nothing.
Some poeple say that sometimes it works by using PTP, but I don't know how to install it...

Thank you for you're time

tbille

Answer (score 0):

If your phone won't turn on, I don't think installing drivers will help. And yet you say that the computer "sees" the phone. In my case I found that after successfully upgrading to 4.4 that my windows PC could no longer "see" my phone unless I went into storage and changed the USB settings to ptp. However, on my Linux machine I can access all folders and storage. So if you have a Linux machine or at least a live disk you may be able to access you internal storage that way. But if the phone isn't turning on, I'm not sure what you can do from that point. Hope something in my ramblings helps. :-)